# What is returned from a SQL query into a PowerShell variable?

Tags: sql, powershell, variables

Here is the function I have setup that works just fine to send queries to a SQL database from PowerShell and return the results (the results are what I don't quite understand)

```
function Invoke-SQL
{
param (
    [string]$server,
    [string]$database,
    [string]$Query
)

$connectionString = "Data Source=$server; " +
"Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
"Initial Catalog=$database"

$connection = new-object 
system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
$command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($Query, $connection)
$connection.Open()

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command

$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

$connection.Close()

$dataSet.Tables
}
```

If I run a query such as the one below (it returns no results, meaning there were no records that existed that matched the condition) why does it return nothing when I just put in `$results`? Why is the result 'Table' when I do `Write-Host $results` ? See below

```
PS>$results = Invoke-SQL -server 'servername' -database 'DBname' -Query "SELECT * FROM [DBname].[dbo].[TableName] WHERE UserID = 'x' AND ComputerName = 'x'"
PS>$results
PS>Write-Host $results
Table
```

When no records are found I thought it would be equal to "" or $null but it is not upon testing

$null test

```
PS>If ($results -eq $null) {
>> write-host "Null"}else{
>> write-host "Not Null"
>> }
Not Null
```

"" test

```
PS>If ($results -eq "") {
>> write-host "Empty"}else{
>> write-host "Not Empty"
>> }
```

If someone could explain this to me, and what options I might have in order to check if a query returns no results, that would be great!

Comment: You can write `($results | Measure-Object).Count` to count the rows in the table (0 = no rows).

Comment: Thanks Bill, that answers half of my question :)

Comment: What happens when you run the commands individually instead as a function? Does the `$dataset` contain any rows? Also, for testing purposes, drop the `| Out-Null`.

Comment: What's the other half of the question?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, Why does `Write-Host $results` return 'Table' ? Honestly i'm not sure what a 'dataset' is, but that's what the Invoke-sql function returns. I found that function online a few months ago.

Comment: Why does it matter? Why do you need `Write-Host`?

Comment: It does not matter at all, simply would like to learn more in depth about what exactly is happening in the code. @Adamar, I will test that tomorrow!

Comment: If you are not sure what a dataset is, It's all documented in the MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx. All the other classes as well. Tons and ton and *tons* of stuff to read.

Comment: Yep.  DataSet, DataTable, DataView, etc.  Honestly you should've read that *before* you started using `System.Data.SqlClient`.  That said, whenever you want to know the answer to, "What type of object is this?" you should try `$results.GetType().FullName` or `$results | Get-Member`.

Answer (score 2):

Read the comments on the question post for more details.

In order to see if records were returned or not, this will return the number of rows (records) returned. Credit to @Bill_Stewart.

```
($results | Measure-Object).Count
```

@Tomalak provided a helpful [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx).

@BaconBits had this helpful tip to get the type of an object

```
$results.GetType().FullName
# or
$results | Get-Member
```

Thank you all for your help.